# point to the last element in a Mat in opencv / c++

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

How to point to the last element in a Mat in opencv?

this is what I have done until now...seems incorrect :(

```
Mat Bdst;
pToLastValue = Bdst.ptr<float>(0);  // pointer to row 0
std::vector< float > vec(pToLastValue, pToLastValue+Bdst.cols); // construct a vector 
float* pToLastValue = &vec.back();
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Pointer to last element can be accessed like this. `float* pToLastValue = static_cast<float*>(Bdst.end<float>().ptr);`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it but I got this error that static_cast type is invalide!

Comment: My bad, didn't test the code. Use C Style type cast like this: `float* pToLastValue = (float*)(Bdst.end<float>().ptr);`

Comment: so, you mean I do not need to convert it to vector and then point to the last element in the vector..yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you a pointer to the last element.

```
Mat Bdst(20, 6, CV_32FC1, data);
float* pToLastValue = reinterpret_cast<float*>((--Bdst.end<float>()).ptr);
```

Remember that `end()` returns an iterator that is past the last element, so you need to decrement to get the last element.

This will also work (just point to the last element of the last row):

```
pToLastValue = Bdst.ptr<float>(Bdst.rows - 1) + Bdst.cols - 1;
```

One thing to careful of is that Mat storage is not always contiguous. e.g. if your Mat is just a submatrix of a larger Mat, there will be gaps between the rows.